# Dynamically added DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dynamically-generated

I have a datagridview that i use to filter another datagridview containing data.The filterGrid is added dynamically.

[image: MyFilterGridView is yellow]

The screen shot shows that i have a MODAL form in order to look up for a record in the database.When I click where the arrow is ,this modal form appears with 2 datagridview.Everyhting is working fine.BUT when i want to look up fagain or a record from another window the filter datagridview is added with columns of the previous form.I think there's something that i must dispose.

[image]

In the event leave of the form i'm disposing the header grid to clean it in order to have a new filter grid added in the nex search that i will do accoriding to the datagridview that contains data but it doesn't work

```
 Private Sub Frm_listeRecherche_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Leave
        Me.Controls.Remove(HeaderGrid)
        HeaderGrid.Dispose()
    End Sub

 Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why would the grid be added dynamically in the first place?  What do you think that you're gaining by that?

Comment: @jmcilhinney  Because my modal form is filled according to the child form of the mdiparent .If you see my 2 pictures ,theres a difference between them .the search form called liste is dynamically filled according to the data send by the child form.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney  you gave me the idea to add manually a datagridview and the fill of columns is made dynamically and i resolved my problem .